# Sans math with lucidabr

Tags: math-mode, fonts, lucida

I have the (Type1) Lucida fonts from TUG, the `lucidabr` package works fine with pdflatex, so all is good.

I'd like, however, to get sans fonts in math, especially letters and numbers. It works by default with `beamer` when I load the `lucidabr` package, so I guess it must be "possible":

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textit{a} = 123 \textit{b} (test): $a = 123 b \; \text{(test)}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But with a standard documentclass I can't reproduce it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\textit{a} = 123 \textit{b} (test): $a = 123 b \; \text{(test)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

What am I missing? Can I make the math look like in `beamer` (without using `beamer`)? The packages `sfmath` and `sansmath` didn't help.

Comment: `beamer` loads `amsmath` automatically, have you tried loading `lucidabr` after `amsmath` in your `article` code to see how it turns out?

Comment: @JamesT I doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried     `mathastext`    package?

Comment: @miltos I had not. Using `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}` after changing `\familydefault` works, at least with simple math. Thanks!

Comment: @Jellby Glad I helped you!